# vuex module appState not working with module namespace passed as first argument

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

if I attempt to pass the namespace as the first argument, as suggested by the docs, I get "undefined" as the value ('test' is set in the module definition)

```
...mapState('guest', {
    email: state => state.email,
}),
```

but it works fine if I just do it this way without the namespace as the first argument

```
...mapState({
    email: state => state.guest.email,
}),
```

I would like to use the shortcut and according to the documentation, the first example should be working... right?

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace

Here is my module definition:

```
const initialState = function(){
    let state = {
        email: null,
    };

    return state;
};    

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: initialState(),
    mutations: {
        fill(state, data) {
            Object.assign(state, data);
        },
        reset(state) {
            Object.assign(state, initialState());
        }
    },
    actions: {
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/kci5h. Can you share more of your store definition? Are you perhaps using `createNamespacedHelpers` when importing `mapState`?

Comment: yeah it sure does seem to be working there, adding to my confusion, I'm not using the `createNamespacedHelpers`, and I've added my module definition, thanks for looking it over @Phil

Comment: _"'test' is set in the module definition"_  not seeing this at all. Your code shows it initialised to `null`. Are you sure you've set a value? What **exactly** is the error?

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion, I removed `test` because I'm moving forward without passing the namespace as the first argument for now since that's working, I'm not receiving an "error", I'm getting the value as "undefined", not "test" or "null" or whatever is defined in my module definition as expected @Phil

Comment: Can you please share the folder structure of you store?

Comment: Where *exactly* are you seeing that `undefined`?

Comment: @Phil Vue dev tools in chrome

Answer (score 2):

Your `computed...mapState` syntax is correct, so likely the problem is with the way the fill mutation is called. Are you namespacing the commit?

This is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-m69m1).

The only other thing to change is `state: initialState` should be `state: Object.assign({}, initialState)`.

The first way sets state to a reference to the `initialState` object, so any changes in the fill mutation will over-write the values of `initialState`, and the reset mutation will have no effect.

**Component**

```js
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState("guest", {
      email: state => state.email
    })
  },
  mounted() {

    // Call the fill mutation with namespace
    this.$store.commit("guest/fill", {
      email: "some@email"
    });

    // Call reset after 2 seconds 
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit("guest/reset");
    }, 2000);
  }
```

**Store**

```js
const initialState = {
  name: "dummyName",
  email: "dummy@initial" // put a value here so we can see if mapState works
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    guest: {
      namespaced: true,
      state: Object.assign({}, initialState),
      mutations: {
        fill(state, data) {
          Object.assign(state, data);
        },
        reset(state) {
          Object.assign(state, initialState);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. I did run into that problem with the reset and had updated my code according to the latest edit.

Comment: Remember the mapState without the namespace passed as the first parameter as shown in my question is working, so the fill is also working.  It's also not even getting the initial state before any changes are made when passing the namespace in first.

Comment: `It's also not even getting the initial state before any changes are made` ... could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sure, so the `initial state` of a property would be the value defined in the vuex definition or specific module definition as in this case.  When using a `mapState` helper, your component would receive the initial state of the mapped properties that it asks for, in this case it should be `null` for email and I'm getting `undefined` when I use the `mapState` helper with the namespace passed in first as shown in my question.

Comment: Since it is working in a clean install, it's possible there's a problem in node_modules, likely `babel`. This line in [vuex source](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/91f3e69ed9e290cf91f8885c6d5ae2c97fa7ab81/src/helpers.js#L21) uses `typeof` which comes in via `babel` (I'm making some assumptions about the way you set up your project). Can you share `package.json`?